# Is the "lambkin" of Revelation 13:11 the "little horn" of Daniel 7:8?

Tags: revelation, daniel, symbolism, nt-use-of-hebrew-bible

> [Rev 13:11 ESV] (11) Then I saw another beast rising out of the earth. It had two horns like a lamb **and it spoke like a dragon**.
>
> > [Rev 13:11 MGNT] (11) καὶ εἶδον ἄλλο θηρίον ἀναβαῖνον ἐκ τῆς γῆς καὶ εἶχεν κέρατα δύο ὅμοια ἀρνίῳ καὶ ἐλάλει ὡς δράκων

[image: Lambkin with little horns]

> [Dan 7:8 ESV] (8) I considered the horns, and behold, there came up among them another horn, a little one, before which three of the first horns were plucked up by the roots. And behold, in this horn were eyes like the eyes of a man, **and a mouth speaking great things**.
>
> > [Dan 7:8 LXX] (8) προσενόουν τοῗς κέρασιν αὐτοῦ καὶ ἰδοὺ κέρας ἕτερον μικρὸν ἀνέβη ἐν μέσῳ αὐτῶν καὶ τρία κέρατα τῶν ἔμπροσθεν αὐτοῦ ἐξερριζώθη ἀπὸ προσώπου αὐτοῦ καὶ ἰδοὺ ὀφθαλμοὶ ὡσεὶ ὀφθαλμοὶ ἀνθρώπου ἐν τῷ κέρατι τούτῳ καὶ στόμα λαλοῦν μεγάλα
>
> [Dan 7:11 ESV] (11) "I looked then **because of the sound of the great words that the horn was speaking**. And as I looked, the beast was killed, and its body destroyed and given over to be burned with fire.
>
> > [Dan 7:8 LXX] (8) προσενόουν τοῗς κέρασιν αὐτοῦ καὶ ἰδοὺ κέρας ἕτερον μικρὸν ἀνέβη ἐν μέσῳ αὐτῶν καὶ τρία κέρατα τῶν ἔμπροσθεν αὐτοῦ ἐξερριζώθη ἀπὸ προσώπου αὐτοῦ καὶ ἰδοὺ ὀφθαλμοὶ ὡσεὶ ὀφθαλμοὶ ἀνθρώπου ἐν τῷ κέρατι τούτῳ καὶ στόμα λαλοῦν μεγάλα

Related:

https://vimeo.com/330235605

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It is essential to count the kingdoms that Daniel 7 lists, and to stay with the context. The word "beast" in Daniel 7 is from Strong's Heb. 2432, and is the same meaning as in Rev. 13.

As provided in the question [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/40449/in-revelation-1311-why-do-english-translations-always-render-%CE%B8%CE%B7%CF%81%E1%BD%B7%CE%BF%CE%BD-as-beast) the beasts of Rev. 13 are metaphors expressed as wild predator animals symbolizing two ruling authorities that persecute and tyrannize the people. The same word "therion" (strong's Gr. 2342) is used for both the sea beast (vs.1,2) and the land beast (vs. 11). The sea beast Rev. was the gentile nation of the Roman empire that surrounded the land beast that had two horns like a lamb.

But, we need to analyze the 4 beasts from Daniel 7, which were 4 kingdoms (Dan. 7:17)

> *"3 And four great beasts came up from the sea, diverse one from another."*  (Dan. 7:3, KJV)

The sea is the metaphor for the gentile nations that surrounded the pleasant land (Psa. 106:24; Jer. 3:19; Dan. 8:9) of Israel, and the remnant of Judea.  This means that these beasts were 4 world powers of the nations outside of Israel.

> *4 The first was like a lion, and had eagle's wings: I beheld till the wings thereof were plucked, and it was lifted up from the earth, and made stand upon the feet as a man, and a man's heart was given to it."* (Dan. 7:4, KJV)

This world power was the first kingdom of Nebuchadnezzar's dream of Dan. 2, and was Babylon.  It was at first powerful under Nebuchadnezzar, but became weak under Belshazzar, the last Babylonian king.

> *"5 And behold another beast, a second, like to a bear, and it raised up itself on one side, and it had three ribs in the mouth of it between the teeth of it: and they said thus unto it, Arise, devour much flesh."*  (Dan. 7:5, KJV)

The second world power (beast) was the Medo-Persian empire under Cyrus and Darius.  It was compared to a bear, though strong it was more lumbering than a lion with one king stronger on one side (Cyrus) than the other king (Darius) and it devoured the first kingdom - Babylon - the three ribs in its mouth.

> *"6 After this I beheld, and lo another, like a leopard, which had upon the back of it four wings of a fowl; the beast had also four heads; and dominion was given to it."* (Dan. 7:6, KJV)

This third world power was weaker than the bear, but still fast with wings.  It was the brass kingdom of Dan. 2:39. The four heads were its rulers with dominion in that kingdom and it conquered the previous world power.  This was Alexander the Great and his four generals: Cassander, Lysimachus, Seleucid, and Ptolemy I. (1)

The fourth kingdom of Dan. 7:7 -

> *"After this I saw in the night visions, and behold a fourth beast, dreadful and terrible, and strong exceedingly; and it had great iron teeth: it devoured and brake in pieces, and stamped the residue with the feet of it: and it was diverse from all the beasts that were before it; and it had ten horns."*  (KJV)

This 4th kingdom stamped out all remnants of the previous 3 world powers and it had 10 horns, that is 10 kings.  This is the same beast kingdom that rose from the sea (gentile nations) of Rev. 13:1-2.  This was the Roman empire the enveloped all the other world powers that had come before it.

As the first kingdom was identified as Babylon, then we have to count from Babylon to identify the 4th world power.  This prophesy does not go beyond that 4th kingdom from Babylon, and it does not go beyond the "end" of Daniel 9:24 - 12:13 when the power of the "holy people" - the Jews - were scattered.  Babylon was the beginning time frame, and the destruction of Jerusalem is the ending time frame.

> *"And the beast which I saw was like unto a leopard, and his feet were as the feet of a bear, and his mouth as the mouth of a lion: and the dragon gave him his power, and his seat, and great authority."*  (Rev. 13:2, KJV)

It had the essence, nature of the leopard beast of Alexander's kingdom, the bear beast of Cyrus and Darius, and the lion beast of Babylon.  It was the amalgamation of all the remnants of the previous 3 kingdoms that made it both strong and broken (Dan. 2:41-42), mixed with iron and clay which would not cleave and bind to one another.

The 10 horns were of this 4th kingdom (Dan. 7:7, Rev. 13:1).  They were 10 kings belonging to this 4th kingdom, therefore they were 10 kings of the Roman empire up to the point of Christ's second appearance (Heb. 9:28) in judgment of Jerusalem: Julius Caesar, Augustus, Tiberius, Caligula, Claudius, Nero, Galba, Otho, Vitellius, and then Vespasian. (2)

The subject of Revelation was the destruction of Jerusalem, the end of the desolations of Jerusalem of which Gabriel had told Daniel (Dan. 9 - 12).  That puts the end of the time frame with the siege and destruction in AD 70.  Vespasian rose to power after the three previous "horns" or kings who had each vied for power over Rome once Nero killed himself.

At the time of the vision and writing of Revelation five of these kings had fallen, and "one is" (Rev. 17:10)  The sixth king was ruling at the time of this book, Nero.  Nero was the last of the Julian line, but both Galba (the 7th) and Otho (8th) appealed to Nero's nature and habits in an attempt to garner support from the people. (3) Thus the sixth king, the one that "now is" was revived through both the 7th and 8th kings.

The three kings that preceded Vespasian were not of the Julian line, and Vespasian's reign began the Flavian dynasty.  This was the Year of Four Emperors (4) during which Rome nearly fell, but Vespasian pulled it back from the brink of the civil wars caused by Galba, Otho, and Vitellius, and took control.  Thus the beast ascended out of the bottomless pit (Rev. 17:8) into which it had fallen with the death of Nero.

Therefore, the little horn (king) that was different from the others (Flavian line) and subdued three kings before it (Dan. 7:24 - Galba, Otho, and Vitellius) was Vespasian.  Describing this king as a little horn spoke of the strength and power of that king.  It did not mean the beast nation was small, only that the power of this horn was small when compared to the power of the previous kings. Vespasian's power had to be assembled from the support of the armies he commanded, and which he gathered together as he marched to Rome in AD 69 because he was not of the Julian line.  His power was not of birth line, but popular support.

Vespasian left his son Titus behind to take charge of the siege of Jerusalem, while he marched to Rome to take charge of the kingdom and pull it back from its death throes.

But, the land beast of Rev 13:11 was not of the power of the ten kings of the sea beast.  It was of the power held over the land... the "earth" of Jerusalem and Judea, and it was the persecuting Sanhedrin... the Pharisees and Sadduccees... the two horns of the land beast.  Speaking as a dragon, that is a serpent was the picture of a lying, deceiving ruling power trying to turn the righteous away from God (Gen. 3:1-5).  The Pharisees and Sadduccees were trying to impose the Mosaic Law upon those newly immersed (baptized) saints who were in Christ and turn them back from their salvation.

The little horn of Dan. 7 was - in my view- Vespasian.  It was certainly of and belonged to the 4th kingdom, the 4th beast power which was Rome during the first century AD.  It was not the same as the land beast of Rev. 13:11.

Notes:

1) Alexander the Great - [here](https://www.ancient.eu/Alexander_the_Great/)

2) List of the Roman Emperors [here](https://www.livius.org/articles/misc/list-of-roman-emperors/)

3) Frequent Mistakes - Part I: The Wounded Head at [ShreddingTheVeil](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2017/11/18/frequent-mistakes-part-i-rev-133-the-wounded-head/)

4) Year of Four Emperors [here](https://www.ancient-origins.net/history-famous-people/year-four-emperors-002052)

Comment: I don't really see the scribes or the Pharisees performing great signs or bringing fire down from heaven. I think this is a more charismatic figure than that, but I'm boggled when it comes to the kind of detail in the history that you seem very comfortable with! I'm very glad for your prowess in that area!

Comment: However you have convinced me that the little horn was most likely Vespasian. That rounds out the Roman side of things nicely, I think. Are you aware of any false Christs of any significance that were miracle workers?

Comment: The "he" and "it" of Rev. 13:13-18 switch back & forth between the 1st beast & the land beast which becomes confusing.  The KJV puts a period at the end of vs. 12, whereas the YLT puts a comma.  Which beast sent fire from heaven?  "He" or "It" of vs 13 refers to the wounded beast that was healed - Rome.  God's judgment = fire from heaven - but it was carried out literally by Titus whose standard was the lightening bolt, & who sent the catapults with huge stones (hail) and fire balls upon Jerusalem during the siege.  Then a semi-colon, & vs. 14 switches back to "it" of the land beast.

Comment: The two horns of the land beast would probably better be viewed as the "king" which Rome appointed over Judea - Herod - and the high priest of the Sanhedrin.

Comment: That's definitely more in the direction that I'm thinking - more Jewish than Roman, though I'm still thinking that there must be a stronger link to the "man of sin" and such elsewhere in the NT. I've been very distracted lately so having a hard time focusing right now but this has all be immensely helpful. Thanks.

Comment: What do you think of Simon Magus as the false prophet/lambkin?:  https://www.britannica.com/biography/Simon-Magus

Comment: The horns signified ruling authority, governing power, kings.  That they were smaller, of the land beast meant their origins were of Judea, the remnant of Israel.  Simon Magus was not a ruler or in any position of authority.  We have to find those two horns, two rulers that were working with the Romans, under Roman authority to persecute the saints.  The more I consider it the more I believe these must have been Herod - appointed gov & king over Judea, and the high priest of the Sanhedrin.  As they were in cahoots with the sea beast, Rome, & as the sea beast was centered in Nero - "one is"...

Comment: ... then, these two smaller horns of the land beast were of the same time as Nero's rule, before he killed himself.  Once Nero was gone, the Roman emperors grew tired of the Judean rulers and "hated her" - the woman.  The goal of the Romans then turned to putting down those two horns of Judea.

Comment: Also, this land beast was of the wild animal description - a predator "beast", and therefore cannot be considered a "lambkin".  That the horns were smaller just meant a relative comparison to the power of the horns / kings of the sea beast.  Still a predator persecuting power, tho.

Comment: Apparently there was widespread Jewish belief that Vespasian was the fulfillment of the Baalam prophecy: https://www.livius.org/articles/religion/messiah/messianic-claimant-14-vespasian/  This could lend credence to both Vespasian being the little horn of Daniel and the first beast of Rev 13.

Comment: Don K Preston sees the land beast as old covenant Israel aka Babylon who "rides on Rome". All that is fine but I don't see the whole miraculous element in any of the explanations I've received.  https://thykingdomcame.com/2014/11/20/who-was-the-land-beast-of-revelation-13-part-2-of-2/

Comment: Symbols & metaphors do not mean miraculous.  I firmly believe the miraculous was the heavenly display in the clouds during that time period as reports were made of ppl seeing armies & horses in the clouds.  But the metaphor of fire doesn't mean literally fire from heaven, just that God's judgment was poured out.  The fire was literally used by the Romans in the war to burn both Jerusalem & the temple.  God caused it, but the Romans were his rod and messenger, his agent of that judgment.  Ironic wasn't it, that the Jews used the Romans to crucify Christ, & God used the Romans to burn it down.

Comment: The issue with Preterism is conjectures

Comment: @Faith - no conjectures.  The OT defines every metaphor God used.  Read the "like" and "as" statements carefully.

Answer (score 3):

There are far more parallels between the beast from the sea (Rev 13:1-8) and Dan 7's four beasts, specifically:

- The beast from the sea in Rev 13:1-8 appears as a composite beast of the four in Dan 7 - lion, bear, leopard with (in reverse order!) 10 horns (same as sea beast) and 7 heads (same number as in Dan 7)
- Both come from, arise out of, the sea
- Rev 13 describes a period of operation of 42 months, Dan 7:25 lists 3½ years
- Both sets of beast oppose God and persecute the saints (Dan 7:21, 25, Rev 13:6, 7, etc)
- Both are blasphemous sets of powers (Dan 7:8, 11, 20, 25, Rev 13:6)

Thus, there is a case for see a parallel between the beasts of Dan 7 (especially the fourth beast) and sea beast of Rev 13.

However, the parallels quoted Rev 13:11, vs Dan 7:8, 11) are a consequence of the primary function of the land beast - it is to give glory to the sea beast by speaking like a dragon and deceiving the inhabitants of the earth.  Thus, the character of the little horn of Dan 7 and the land beast of Rev 13 are quite different.

The word used to describe the land beast is ἀρνίον (arnion) which occurs 30 times in the NT as follows:

- John 21:15 describing the Christian community
- 28 times in Revelation to describe Jesus as a lamb
- Rev 13:11 to describe the land beast

Thus, there is little evidence to link the land beast of Rev 13:11-17 with the beasts of Dan 7, but there is much more to link the sea beast with Dan 7.  The little horn of Dan 7 arises from among the 10 horns and become exceedingly great - quite unlike the two horns of the land beast with two (possible diminutive?) horns.

The links that do exist are because the land beast wants to support the sea beast.

Comment: John 1:29 uses ἀμνὸς. Ex 12:21 uses πρόβατον. This seems to require more chewing (for me, anyway)...

Comment: Woops - quite correct.  I will correct this.

Comment: What do you think of Simon Magus as the false prophet/lambkin?:  https://www.britannica.com/biography/Simon-Magus

Comment: Whatever we make of the Lamb-beast (more correctly the land beast) it is a large international power that deceives the whole world, exercises all the power of the sea beast, causes fire to come down from heaven and even controls trade by deciding who can buy and sell.  Simon Magnus does not fit any of these specifications.

Comment: Are you sure you are not referring to Daniel's little horn?

Comment: The statements above are direct quotes from Rev 13:11-17.  I actually had the passage open at the time and the little horn never crossed my mind.

Comment: I guess then that you are reading "land" to mean Earth rather than Israel?

Comment: The Greek is "ge" which means arable land, or the inhabitants that live on the arable land.  The only way "ge" could mean Israel is if "ge" referred specifically to the land of Israel.  "Inhabitants of the land" occurs 13 times in Revelation and appears to refer to the wicked who are deceived.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the “lambkin” of Revelation 13:11 the “little horn” of Daniel 7:8?

I believe so.

> Dan 7:7 After this I saw in the night visions, and behold a fourth beast, dreadful and terrible, and strong exceedingly; and it had great iron teeth: it devoured and brake in pieces, and stamped the residue with the feet of it: and it was diverse from all the beasts that were before it; and it had ten horns.
>   Dan 7:8 I considered the horns, and, behold, there came up among them another little horn, before whom there were three of the first horns plucked up by the roots: and, behold, in this horn were eyes like the eyes of man, and a mouth speaking great things.

Here a ten horned beast arises and after it rises the little horn who takes control of this ten horned kingdom.

Who do you think the little horn is in Revelation? Same guy that arises AFTER the ten horned beast rises up.

> Rev 13:1 And I stood upon the sand of the sea, and saw a beast rise up out of the sea, having seven heads and ten horns, and upon his horns ten crowns, and upon his heads the name of blasphemy.

Same beast Daniel described but with the added 7 heads.

> Rev 13:2 And the beast which I saw was like unto a leopard, and his feet were as the feet of a bear, and his mouth as the mouth of a lion: and the dragon gave him his power, and his seat, and great authority.
>   Rev 13:3 And I saw one of his heads as it were wounded to death; and his deadly wound was healed: and all the world wondered after the beast.
>   Rev 13:4 And they worshipped the dragon which gave power unto the beast: and they worshipped the beast, saying, Who is like unto the beast? who is able to make war with him?
>   Rev 13:5 And there was given unto him a mouth speaking great things and blasphemies; and power was given unto him to continue forty and two months.
>   Rev 13:6 And he opened his mouth in blasphemy against God, to blaspheme his name, and his tabernacle, and them that dwell in heaven.
>   Rev 13:7 And it was given unto him to make war with the saints, and to overcome them: and power was given him over all kindreds, and tongues, and nations.
>   Rev 13:8 And all that dwell upon the earth shall worship him, whose names are not written in the book of life of the Lamb slain from the foundation of the world.
>   Rev 13:9 If any man have an ear, let him hear.
>   Rev 13:10 He that leadeth into captivity shall go into captivity: he that killeth with the sword must be killed with the sword. Here is the patience and the faith of the saints.
>   Rev 13:11 And I beheld another beast coming up out of the earth; and he had two horns like a lamb, and he spake as a dragon.
>   Rev 13:12 And he exerciseth all the power of the first beast before him, and causeth the earth and them which dwell therein to worship the first beast, whose deadly wound was healed.

And here comes the little horn just like it is in Daniel.

Daniel - ten horned beast arises, little horn comes next and is the person of authority and power over the ten horned beast.
Revelation - ten horned beast arises, false prophet comes next and is the person of authority and power over the ten horned beast.

Neither book uses the term "Antichrist" but we know that same person is found in both books under a different name. Isn't it clear that the little horn and FP are the AC?

little horn = false prophet = antichrist.

Why two little horns?

The two horns of the false prophet shows that he is going to be two kings. He is the 7th and 8th king mentioned here:

> Rev 17:10 And there are seven kings: five are fallen, and one is, and the other is not yet come; and when he cometh, he must continue a short space.
>   Rev 17:11 And the beast that was, and is not, **even he is the eighth, and is of the seven**, and goeth into perdition.

Answer (score 0):

The land beast of Revelation 13 is not the little horn of Daniel 7. It is a separate power.

The sea beast of Revelation 13 is the little horn of Daniel 7.

1. Rises from sea (verse 1). - All beasts of Daniel 7 arise from the sea
2. Composite of the four beasts of Daniel chapter 7 (verse 2).
3. Strong political power (verses 3, 7) - similar to the little horn (Daniel 7:8 - Plucks up 3 horns out of the 10)
4. Strong religious power (verses 3, 8) - Little horn was different from the other horns before it (Daniel 7:24, Daniel 7:8 - Speaks)
5. Guilty of blasphemy (verses 1, 5, 6). Little horn speaks great words against the Most High (Dan 7:25)
6. Wars with and overcomes the saints (verse 7). Little horn fights the saints (Dan 7:25)
7. Rules for 42 months (verse 5). - 1260 days: The little horn wins against the saints for time, times and dividing of times (1 year + 2 year + 1/2 year = 3.5 years = 1260 days)
8. The fourth beast of Dan 7 from which the little horn arises is described as a great and dreadful beast similar to the sea beast of Rev 13.

The land beast on the other hand:

1. Arises from earth - opposite of sea - Gen 1:9 - God gathered waters together to one place and dry land appeared in the drained areas. Thus dry land represent places where there are not much people. A sparsely occupied territory
2. The beasts of Daniel 7 (of which the sea beast of Rev 13 is an expansion) arise as the winds hit upon the sea (Dan 7:2), unlike the lamb like beast which arises peacefully - not through war

   > Jer 49:32 And their camels shall be a booty, and the multitude of their cattle a spoil: and I will scatter into all winds them that are in the utmost corners; and I will bring their calamity from all sides thereof, saith the LORD.

   ```
   Winds represent war, spoiling, destruction
   ```
3. This beast arises after the first beast was wounded. This happens after the 42 months of the beast's rule. This comes to 1260 years. Thus a specific time frame is denoted during which the land beast rises to supremacy.
4. The land beast though appearing to be a lamb (Christ like) was a deceiver. It is actually an agent of Satan and speaks like the dragon. Thus it is comparable to a false prophet who speak lies in the name of the Lord (claiming to be the Lord's prophets they say things which the Lord has not spoken). In Rev 19:20 we find "a false prophet" who does the exact things that this land beast does. Thus the land beast is the false prophet of Rev 19.

To know the identities of the little horn, the sea beast and the land beast, I recommend the following articles, which describe it accurately and concisely:

1. [Little Horn](https://www.amazingfacts.org/media-library/study-guide/e/4992/t/who-is-the-antichrist-)
2. [Sea Beast and Land Beast](https://www.amazingfacts.org/media-library/study-guide/e/4997/t/the-mark-of-the-beast)